# Attendance and payroll management design

Tags: database-design, sqlite

I am developing an Android app for the first time. For the database I am using SQLite . I am new to the concept of relational database. I am creating an app for attendance and payroll management. I am planing to add 3 tables:

1. employee
2. attendance
3. salary

In the first table, I entered the details of employees where the joining date and end date is defined. How to calculate the attendance based on the specified date? I will be using `sysdate/timestamp` for each day attendance as column and value will be `boolean`.

Also I will have a salary table. How to link it with the employee table to get `emp_id` (foreign key ) and name (how to link name)?

Please help me with the query and understanding concept of relations of the tables and also if any database design you all can recommended would help.